# される and られる confusing meaning

Tags: passive-voice, causation

I have some trouble with my Japanese studies. I am stuck on some causative passive meanings.

So far, if I am right, there are 3 causative-passive forms:

られる: X is being ... by Y

させられる: Y forces X to .../ X is forced by Y to...

させる: X makes Y to .../ X allows Y to ...

However, I am not able to understand the される.

For example:

その話しはもうちょっと考えさせて: Let me think about the story

その話しはもうちょっと考えられ : I can think of that story a little more

英語は世界中で話されています: English is spoken all over the world

英語は世界中で話られています: English is spoken all over the world

I can't seem to associate される to any of them. I can understand that される is somehow related to the subject, but in what sense? How does it differ from られる?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, your problem is with the されて in

> 英語は世界中で**話されて**います

But this さ just comes from the す part of 話す. To make the passive form for group 1 verbs you take the stem for negative verbs and add れる. So for example the negative of 話す is 話**さ**ない, the stem is 話さ, and then we add れる to give 話される.

For group 2 verbs you take the masu-stem and add られる which is the form you talked about above.

Finally, your last sentence:

> 英語は世界中で**話(?)**られています

is ungrammatical because you have missed the す part (or a modification of it) from 話す.

Comment: The pedant in me also feels the need to point out that there is one passive form, one causitive from and one causitive-passive form, rather than three causitive passive forms.

Comment: Like, thanks, seriously, for the past hours I just could see what the さ was there for. Dud Thanks a lot. And thanks for the correction too.